# i tried to ball move while sensore change

Tags: android, sensors

The following code I have used to get the x,y values of sensor change.
Based on this I am trying to move the ball on the screen.

```
     private SensorManager sensorMgr;
     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
     private TextView accuracyLabel;
     private TextView xLabel, yLabel, zLabel;
     private Button calibrateButton;
     public int mScrWidth,mScrHeight,wh,hgt;
     public float x, y, z;

     // deltas for calibration
     private float cx, cy, cz;

     private long lastUpdate = -1;
     public float mSpdx;
     public float mSpdy;
     public CollisionSurface cf=null;


     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        xLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        yLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        zLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        sensorMgr= (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();


          Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)    {
            w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
          wh =  mScrWidth = size.x;

          hgt = mScrHeight = size.y; 
        }else{
            Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
          wh=  mScrWidth = d.getWidth(); 

          xLabel.setText(""+wh);  


        } 

        /*        ((SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)).registerListener(
       new SensorEventListener() {    
        @Override  
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {  
           //set ball speed based on phone tilt (ignore Z axis)
         mSpdx = event.values[1];
         mSpdy = event.values[0];
         //timer event will redraw ball
        }
               @Override  
           public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {} //ignore this event
          },
          ((SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE))
          .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(o), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

      */

         cf=new CollisionSurface(this.getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(cf);


    }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this, SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
      sensorMgr = null;

      cx = 0;
      cy = 0;
      cz = 0;
     }

     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

   sensorMgr.registerListener(this, sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                 SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
         // ...and the orientation sensor
       boolean accelSupported = sensorMgr.registerListener(this, SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

  if (!accelSupported) {
   // on accelerometer on this device
   sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this, SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
   //accuracyLabel.setText(R.string.no_accelerometer);
  }
 }

 // from the android.hardware.SensorListener interface
 public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
  // this method is called very rarely, so we don't have to
  // limit our updates as we do in onSensorChanged(...)
  if (sensor == SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
   switch (accuracy) {
   case SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE:
    //accuracyLabel.setText(R.string.accuracy_unreliable);
    break;
   case SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW:
    //accuracyLabel.setText(R.string.accuracy_low);
    break;
   case SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM:
    //accuracyLabel.setText(R.string.accuracy_medium);
    break;
   case SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH:
    //accuracyLabel.setText(R.string.accuracy_high);
    break;
   }
  }
 }


 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent)
    {
        {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                // the values you were calculating originally here were over 10000!
               x= (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1], 2); 
                y= (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[2], 2);
            }

            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {

            }
        }
    }

 @Override
 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (sensor == SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
   long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   // only allow one update every 100ms, otherwise updates
   // come way too fast and the phone gets bogged down
   // with garbage collection
   if (lastUpdate == -1 || (curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
    lastUpdate = curTime;

    x = values[DATA_X];
    y = values[DATA_Y];
    z = values[DATA_Z];

   // xLabel.setText(String.format("X: %+2.5f (%+2.5f)", (x+cx), cx));
   // yLabel.setText(String.format("Y: %+2.5f (%+2.5f)", (y+cy), cy));
   // zLabel.setText(String.format("Z: %+2.5f (%+2.5f)", (z+cz), cz));
     }
     }
     }
```

i cant get x,y,z values in tilt of phone..   what changes i need to do..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements SensorEventListener{

        // deltas for calibration
        private float cx, cy, cz;
        private int SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER = Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER;
        private SensorManager sensorMgr;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private TextView accuracyLabel;
        private TextView xLabel, yLabel, zLabel;
        private Button calibrateButton;
        public int mScrWidth, mScrHeight, wh, hgt;
        public float x, y, z;
        float lastUpdate;

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Point size = new Point();
            WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
                wh = mScrWidth = size.x;

                hgt = mScrHeight = size.y;
            } else {
                Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
                wh = mScrWidth = d.getWidth();

                xLabel.setText("" + wh);

            }

            /*
             * ((SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)).
             * registerListener( new SensorEventListener() {
             * 
             * @Override public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { //set ball
             * speed based on phone tilt (ignore Z axis) mSpdx = event.values[1];
             * mSpdy = event.values[0]; //timer event will redraw ball }
             * 
             * @Override public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
             * {} //ignore this event },
             * ((SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE))
             * .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(o),
             * SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
             */

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            if (sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
                sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);
                sensorMgr = null;
            }

            cx = 0;
            cy = 0;
            cz = 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

            // ...and the orientation sensor


            if (sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
                sensorMgr.registerListener(this,
                        sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
        }


        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
                if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                    // the values you were calculating originally here were over
                    // 10000!
                    x = sensorEvent.values[0];
                    y = sensorEvent.values[1];

                    System.out.println(x);
                    System.out.println(y);
                    System.out.println(sensorEvent.values[2]);
                }           
        }



        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

Comment: you have to make changes accordingly as my code was only intended to extract the x, y, z values, please check and let me know